# schedule that runs in a specific time range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduler

I want to define a scheduler that runs at every minute within a specific time range. I am using python 3.

I wrote the code like below-

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.day.at("00:10").to.day.at("06:10").do(somthing)
```

but it's not working. Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you add a runnable piece of code? What's "not working" and what do you expect to see?

Comment: Actually I want to run a schedule every 1 minute within a specific time range; like from 00:10 to 06:10. but I can not define the time range here.

Comment: How about you simply do a schedule for every minute (idk how `schedule` works), but inside the "do" part add an additional `if` statement to check if time is between `00:10` and `06:10`